# how can I solve Pseudocode + function

Tags: recursion

if condition of function f :

```
function f(x : integer) : integer;
begin
if x = 1 then
f = 0
else
f = x * f(x - 1) + x^2
end;
```

find value of f(4)

show me the step by step for calculate please

sorry for my poor english..

Comment: Can you please show how you attempted this and where you are having problems?

Comment: also, what language are you writing in?

Comment: i try to x=4, f(x)=x*f(x-1)+x^2, f(4)=4*f(3)*16 , than i don't know how to do next.. now i knew that thank for your advice : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a real language (Python) your code would be written as follows:

```
def f(x):
    return 0 if x == 1 else x * f(x - 1) + pow(x, 2)
```

### Going Down

Lets assume we start with `x=4`

```
f(4) = 4 * f(3) + 16
```

So we nee to evaluate `f(3)`

```
f(3) = 3 * f(2) + 9
```

and then evaluate `f(2)`

```
f(2) = 2 * f(1) + 4
```

Again we need `f(1)`

```
f(1) = 0
```

### Coming Back Up

Now we have all the values we need we can go back up the stack of expressions:

```
f(2) = 2 * 0 + 4 = 4

f(3) = 3 * 4 + 9 = 21

f(4) = 4 * 21 + 16 = 100
```

Comment: umm thank you! btw i just helped by my friend his solve is.. 
f=4*(3*f(2)+9)+16
f=4*(3*(2*f(1)+4)+9)+16 
f=4*(3*(2*0+4)+9)+16
f=4*(3*(4)+9)16
f=4*(21)+16
f=84+16
f=100

Comment: f(1) = 0, that is why your calculation by deviating from OP's. But nice explanation. +1

Comment: Modified answer such that `f(1) = 0`